# .post-text :last-child should have the child combinator '>' in mobile.css

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, mobile-web

In `mobile.css` (the mobile version of Stack Overflow) there's a CSS rule:

```css
.post-text :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Currently this rule applies to every element in `.post-text` that is the last child of its parent, even if the parent is not `.post-text`. As you can see in the following screenshot, this also sets the bottom margin to zero on the last elements in each `li` and so on:

[image: Current CSS - highlighted elements]

When I add the *child combinator* (`.post-text > :last-child`), everything works as expected:

[image: Proposed CSS - highlighted elements]

(The answer in the screenshots is https://stackoverflow.com/a/53251603).
This only applies to the **mobile** layout of SO, so you'll probably need to test this with a mobile user-agent.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I see a visible difference in the layout between the two screenshots. We're (albeit slowly) working on deprecating mobile views in favor of a responsive UI. Given that this doesn't seem to be breaking anything, we're gonna leave the mobile styling as is at this time.