# Missing margin after list items (on mobile site)

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

On the mobile site, list item layout is currently quite confusing. In the screenshot below, the second paragraph of the first item is incorrectly displayed right above the second item (a bottom margin is missing).

> [image: missing margin after list items]

It's caused by [this easily fixable bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382540/post-text-last-child-should-have-the-child-combinator-in-mobile-css):

```css
.post-text :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

This rule is clearly broken, since it applies to anything that is the last child of its parent, instead of only the last child in `.post-text`. After changing the selector to `.post-text > :last-child`, it works correctly (as shown in the picture above).

<sub>The screenshot answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/32733650/2992984</sub>

Comment: The mobile site is not maintained much, if at all. For me (on a mobile) I see the bug in the mobile site but not in the full (responsive) site (click the "full site" link at the bottom of page). If recommend you try the full site unless you have a reason not to.